# If $f$ is an entire function with a non dense image then it is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it true that if $f$ is entire with a non dense image then it is constant? Can anybody help with the proof? Or give a counter example. Thank you

Comment: the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337154/how-to-show-image-of-a-non-constant-entire-function-is-dense-in-mathbbc

Comment: Another equivalent question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133098/proving-an-entire-function-which-misses-a-ball-is-constant?rq=1