# Proving an entire, complex function with below bounded modulus is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I show that an entire function $f$ with the property $|f(z)| \geq 1$ must be constant?

I'm aware of Liouville's theorem, just not sure how to apply it here.

Answer (score 3):

The map $z\mapsto 1/f(z)$ is

- well defined;
- entire;
- bounded on the complex plane.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133098/proving-an-entire-function-which-misses-a-ball-is-constant) is a generalization.

Answer (score 2):

If $|f| \geq 1$, then $|\frac{1}{f}| \leq 1$.  Apply Liouville.

Answer (score 0):

As a stronger alternative to Liouville's theorem, it is worth mentioning that we can apply Picard's little theorem to this particular example.

> **Little Picard Theorem**. *If a function $f : \mathbb{C} → \mathbb{C}$ is entire and non-constant, then the set of values that $f(z)$ assumes is either the whole complex plane or the plane minus a single point.*

In layman's terms, Picard's little theorem says that **any** entire analytic function whose range omits two points must be a constant function.

---

Note that the image of $f$ is missing infinitely many points, namely anything in the unit disk. Thus, $f$ must be constant by Picard's little theorem.

Comment: the Picard theorem is way too complicated for this question (proving the Liouville theorem takes 3 lines from the Cauchy integral formula)

Comment: @user1952009 Agreed. I just wanted to give the OP a second approach to the problem for the sake of completeness.